# Are the parameters of Non-linear regression independent of each other?

Tags: standard-error, error, error-propagation, growth-model

I'm propagating error in the parameters determined by the following growth function...

$$
\hat{y} = ae^\frac{t}{b} + (1- a)e^\frac{t}{c}
$$

Say I have another model that uses the parameters {a,b,c} to estimate another rate $z$.

$$
z = a \times b \times c
$$

I want to know the 95% confidence interval for z. Can I just assume the true parameter for $z$ falls between the product of the 2.5% limit for {a,b,c} and the product of 97.5% for {a,b,c}?

Comment: It is hard to determine what your notation means, since "$*$" and "$\pm$" are employed in unusual ways. Could you explain the sense in which "$z=a*b*c$" is a "model" and what your formula for $\epsilon$ means?

Comment: I see what you mean, I edited my question

Comment: Have you considered reparameterizing your model to include $z$ directly, such as $$y=\frac{z}{bc} e^{t/b} + \left(1 - \frac{z}{bc}\right) e^{t/c}\text{?}$$

Comment: Really interesting notion, the actual model is a little more complex but I think I will try that out.

Comment: When you fit the model with Maximum Likelihood (assuming that is appropriate), it's a great solution, because you can then obtain a confidence interval for $z$ using your favorite ML-based method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of the confidence intervals for $a,b,c$ will *not* be a valid confidence interval for $z$, even in the case of $a,b,c$ being independent (which, for the record, is especially unlikely). As a simple example, suppose we only considered $a$ and $b$ and the confidence interval for $a \times b$. If the each of these confidence intervals were (-1,1), then using that formula, we would end up with (1,1) as our confidence interval for $a \times b$. If $a$ and $b$ were independent, this would clearly be false.

If you have the covariance matrix for $a, b, c$, and a fairly large sample size, a straightforward method is to use the delta method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method). In general, if $\beta$ is your vector of parameters, if you'd like a confidence interval of $f(\beta)$, it can be created from

$f(\hat \beta) \pm z * ( f'(\hat \beta)^T * \hat \Sigma * f'(\hat \beta))$

where $f$ is your function of interest (in this case, we can think of $f(\beta) = \beta_1 \times \beta_2 \times \beta_3$ where $\beta_1 = a, \beta_2 = b, \beta_3 = c$), $f'$ is the vector of derivatives and $\hat \Sigma$ is the estimated covariance matrix and $z$ is the standard z-score associated with the confidence interval.

Comment: Would you be able to point me to somewhere where I could read up on why what you said in the first paragraph is true?

Comment: Wow, that statement was incorrect! See new edit. I was thinking about the about the additive scale when I wrote that. Thanks for not blindly accepting  that statement!

Comment: What do the stars and crosses denote? If simply multiplication, I'd recommend leaving them out, as is standard mathematical notation.